# Setup of Openpose: opencv2/core.hpp not found

Tags: opencv, caffe, openpose

I'm trying to setup Openpose + Pyopenpose following in a container following this gist: https://github.com/christian-lanius/PyOpenPose.

That works fine until the caffe compilation step, during which a `opencv2/core.hpp not found` exception is thrown (note that the OpenCV installation step terminates successfully). While there are a number of rather similar questions around, I nonetheless couldn't find a viable solution in my context.

I'm assuming I have to somehow link OpenCV so it can be found by other applications - do you guys have any idea how to fix or circumvent this error?

Thanks!